# How to tell old-school `object` and `record` apart?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

```
program Project15;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Rtti, System.TypInfo;

type
  TRecord = record
  public
    AField: integer;
    constructor Init(test: integer);
  end;

  TOldObject = object
  public
    AField: integer;
    constructor Init(test: integer);
    procedure Fancy; virtual;    <<--- compiles
    class operator Implicit(test: TRecord): TOldObject; <<-- does not compile.
  end;

procedure IsObjectARecord;
var
  ARecord: TRecord;
  AObject: TOldObject;
  v: TValue;
  s: String;
begin
  v:= TValue.From(ARecord);
  case v.Kind of
    tkRecord: WriteLn('it''s a Record');
  end;
  ARecord:= TRecord.Init(10);
  AObject.Init(10);
  v:= TValue.From(AObject);
  case v.Kind of
    tkRecord: begin
      WriteLn('object is a record?');
      if v.IsObject then s:= 'true'
      else s:= 'false';
      WriteLn('isObject = ' + s);
      WriteLn('ToString says: '+v.ToString);
    end;
  end;

end;
{ TOldSkool }

constructor TOldObject.Init(test: integer);
begin
  AField:= 10;
end;

constructor TRecord.Init(test: integer);
begin
  AField:= 10;
end;

begin
  IsObjectARecord;
  Readln;
end.
```

The outcome of the test proc reads:

> ARecord is a Record
>   AObject is a record?
>   isObject(AObject) = false
>   AObject.ToString says: (record)

However `object` <> `record` from a functionality point of view.
Object supports inheritance and virtual calls.
Record supports class operators.

**Is there a way to tell TP5.5-objects and records apart using RTTI?**
**Is there even a need to tell them apart -ever-?**

<sub>Note that I'm not planning to use `object`, I'm just enumerating types using RTTI so that my generic HashTable with pointers can clean up after itself properly.

Yes I know that object lives on the stack by default (or the heap with special effort) and do not normally need to be freed.</sub>

<del><sub>Bonus points if someone knows why virtual calls with TP5.5-objects no longer work, they used to work in Delphi 2007</sub></del>

Comment: Instances of `object` can live on either stack or heap. Just like records.

Comment: FWIW, if you turn the colon into a semicolon, the virtual method will compile. IOW, your syntax error does not compile, but virtual methods do (tested in XE4). The operator does not compile, as expected.

Comment: Thanks Rudy; lesson learned; do not code when caffeine levels are low;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the very best of my knowledge, in the eyes of Delphi's RTTI framework, an old-style object cannot be distinguished from a record. This program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Rtti;

type
  TOldObject = object
  end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
begin
  RttiType := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TOldObject));
  Writeln(TValue.From(RttiType.TypeKind).ToString);
  Writeln(RttiType.IsRecord);
  Readln;
end.
```

outputs

```
tkRecord
TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Old object is deprecated.

So you should not use it in conjunction with the new rtti.

First step of deprecation was to disallow virtual methods. Due I suppose to compiler regressions.

This is the Embarcadero decision to mimic C# and his struct / class paradigm. Wrong decision imho.

Comment: @Arnaud This does not answer the question that was asked. You should make it a comment instead.

Comment: This should indeed be a comment, and virtual methods are not disallowed. There is a syntax error in that line and that is why it doesn't compile.

Comment: Object is just broken since Delphi 2010.http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/01/29/record-and-object-issue-in-Delphi-2010 so do not tell me it is still available. IMHO I answered the question about rtti: object is not too be used any more so new rtti just does not support it, nor the older rtti since it was already focusing on class.

Comment: @Johan Because you should use `object` in 2014, if you want to scale on concurrent programming, as you would do with nice modern languages like Rust - see http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/10/09/Good-old-object-is-not-to-be-deprecated-it-is-the-future

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez You answered a different question. You answered, "Should I use object?"

Comment: The non-initialization of object was fixed I think.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I answered: "RTTI is not accurate since object is officially deprecated - the only existing/supported type is record". Last paragraph is a trolling subject, but it does make sense to me - for full argumentation and comparison with modern concurrent language, see http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/10/09/Good-old-object-is-not-to-be-deprecated-it-is-the-future - this illustrates my last paragraph. But the first 3 paragraphs do directly answer to the question. We could do semantics for ours, but I have no evidence that the non-initialization of object problem was fixed.

Comment: So your answer is that new style RTTI does not support object?